# Mouse hover problem combining QLineSeries and QScatterSeries on a QChart (PySide6)

Tags: qt, pyside6, qchart

I am writing a small python module to visualize data on a chart using Qt (PySide6). My goal is to distinguish between mouse hovers on `QLineSeries`'s lines and points. Since it does not seem to be possible with the current implementation, I tried to combine a `QLineSeries` with a `QScatterSeries` and manage the hover signals separately. The problem is that adding a `QScatterSeries` prevents any previously added series from emitting hover signals.
Is this expected behavior or am I doing something wrong?
Here is a minimal example to reproduce the issue

```
from PySide6.QtCharts import QChart, QChartView, QLineSeries, QScatterSeries
from PySide6.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow
from PySide6.QtGui import QPen, QColor


def on_line_hover():
    print("line hover")


def on_point_hover():
    print("point hover")


app = QApplication()
main_window = QMainWindow()
main_window.show()
chart = QChart()
chart_view = QChartView(chart, main_window)
main_window.setCentralWidget(chart_view)
line = QLineSeries()
line.setPen(QPen(QColor("black"), 10))
line.append(0, 0)
line.append(1, 1)
line.hovered.connect(on_line_hover)
points = QScatterSeries()
points.setPen(QPen(QColor("blue"), 10))
points.append(0.25, 0.25)
points.append(0.75, 0.75)
points.hovered.connect(on_point_hover)

chart.addSeries(line)
chart.addSeries(points)
chart.createDefaultAxes()


app.exec()
```

Note: In the example above for whatever reason, hovering on the `QLineSeries` works outside the chart where the line goes slightly out of the border, although it is clipped by the border itself.

Comment: It is emitting both line and point hover signals for me.  But the signals stretch beyond the border for me as well.  What is the problem you are having?

Comment: Thanks for trying it out! For me it only emits point hover signals. I get line hover signals only beyond the chart borders. Are you also using pyside6? Btw. I am working on Linux, not sure whether it makes a difference

Comment: I was working on windows but I just fired up my ubuntu pc and it shows the line hover on it too.  I am using PySide6

Comment: The signals beyond the edges is much worse on ubuntu though.

Comment: I can configrm that it works on Win. It seems to be an issue only on ubuntu

Comment: Opened a bug ticket for pyside https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1971.